# R: merge two equal sized arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I'm sure this question must be trivial but I couldn't find a similar question on stack overflow. I wish to merge `array.A` and `array.B` so that the `result` is an array of arrays of the values of arrays A and B.

For example:

```
array.A <- array(1:9, dim=c(3,3))
array.B <- array(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 9 )], dim=c(3,3))

> array.A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9

> array.B
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "D"  "G" 
[2,] "B"  "E"  "H" 
[3,] "C"  "F"  "I"
```

And I wish to merge them so that the resulting array would look like this:

```
> result
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] ["A",1]  ["D",4]  ["G",7] 
[2,] ["B",2]  ["E",5]  ["H",8]
[3,] ["C",3]  ["F",6]  ["I",9]
```

I've tried using `cbind` and `rbind` but this isn't what I'm looking for (I'm not trying to concatenate the arrays). I can't seem to find a simple solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you want as an output exactly - is `out <- array(Map(c, array.A, array.B), dim=dim(array.A) )` close enough, which allows you to have `out[1,1]` containing two values?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's pretty much what I'm after although I need to be able to select between the two values. Something like `out[1,1][1]` for `"A"` and `out[1,1][2]` for `1`. I don't know if this is possible or not?

Comment: Sure, out[1,1][[1]][1] should do it. You just have to access the contents of the list first

Comment: If you want a 3-dimensional array, `abind::abind(array.A, array.B, along = 3)`, though that does coerce the numbers to character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a typical kind of structure, but you can put `list` objects inside a `matrix` or `array`:

```
out <- array(Map(list, array.A, array.B), dim=dim(array.A) )
#     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]  
#[1,] List,2 List,2 List,2
#[2,] List,2 List,2 List,2
#[3,] List,2 List,2 List,2

out[1,1]
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "A"

out[1,1][[1]][1]
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

out[1,1][[1]][2]
#[[1]]
#[1] "A"
```

Comment: Thanks very much! While this answers my question perfectly, I should mention that for my real data I ended up abandoning this method (merging the arrays) as an approach as it was quite a clunky way of achieving my goal (I'm still an R novice).